# Console errors. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: http, certificate

I'm getting them on my links in my head.

`GET https://fr.s.us/js/jquery-ui.css net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

`GET https://fr.s.us/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

`GET https://fr.s.us/js/jquery-ui.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

Someone please enlighten me on these jquery console errors..

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

Comment: What OS and browser were you using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23688565/632951

Comment: @cooking-good Ur server http/apache? why so not try nginx to install certificate is free, look https://www.nginx.com/blog/free-certificates-lets-encrypt-and-nginx/ ... im used and its excellent, expire 90 days, can u reinstall certificate is free.

Comment: Is there a way if these console errors can get handle with javascript??

Can we access console errors with any javascript api or event?

Answer (score 116):

I am assuming you're using Chrome.

If so, the root problem is a certificate mismatch / expired certificate.

You can see this for yourself in the [code here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/renderer/security_filter_peer.cc?pathrev=261323).

Note in particular the use of the very constant you reference in the code on line 48 of the C++ file I sent you:

```
 case net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE:
```

The current version of this file is [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/renderer/security_filter_peer.cc&type=cs&sq=package:chromium&l=48). The error status ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE may not any longer be on line 48 but the error code still exists in the SSL certificate portion of the code.

Note:
Make sure to use the hostname which is listed in the SSL certificate, chrome automatically switches to the right hostname if you are browsing but not when using javascript.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the right answer. Thanks

Comment: You can bypass the certificate mismatch error by opening Chrome from the terminal: `Chrome --ignore-certificate-errors`. It should not be necessary to say this, but only do this if you know what you are doing!

Comment: how i can configure this from the setting in google chrome ?

Comment: Also note: When browsing a hostname chrome will automatically switch to the certificate host. (for example: stripping the "www.")
But they forgot to implement that feature for the javascript parser, so you need to specify the correct domain which is listed on the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 29):

The supplied host is not resolving for me (custom DNS or self configured host?) so I can only hazard to guess.

But as you are requesting the resources over SSL it is likely the certificate is invalid. Either it is self-signed and has not been added to your browser/OS exceptions or it is otherwise invalid.

Try the URI directly in the same browser and inspect the certificate.

Edit: this is in no way related to jQuery, JavaScript or CSS directly.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem with chrome when I was working on a WordPress site. I added this code

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = false;
```

into the theme's functions.php file - it asks you to log in again when you save the file but once it's logged in it works straight away.

Comment: Although the question was asked over a year ago (Feb 2014), this answer may fix a recent change to Google Chrome (June 2015) that causes net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE issues on WordPress/WooCommerce websites. More details here: http://frique.me/blog/chrome-wordpress-ssl-bug/

Answer (score 6):

This can also happen if you have Chrome update automatically. Open Check `chrome://help`. The status should be:

> *Google Chrome is up to date.*

Sometimes the status is requesting for a Chrome restart. In this case I had similar issues with several resources failing to load due to `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`. After restarting Chrome, everything worked normally.

Comment: It was exactly the case. It helped address the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When I had the problem recently it was a cross site issue where our dev server hosts our analytics software as well as the application. In the other environments the chrome console would show this error and the javascript file (tracker) on the dev server as the source. This was causing issues for QA personnel who were trying to view the analytics data for their environment (nothing was being captured because of this issue).

The solution to fix this in-house was to add the SSL certificate the DEV site was using to the Trusted People store on the QA people's machine.

If this was a problem in production I would most likely move the javascript into the actual web apps.

Answer (score 2):

Try to open it in an incognito window. I hope this will help. Alternatively, you could modify `application/.htaccess` like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, sometimes when i tests my MVC project by a `localhost` `https` url (E.g. `https://localhost:44373/`), the **Chrome** raise this error: `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` for the website resources (such as `JS` files).

So i resolve it by **Clear Cache**. Then i refresh the page and Chrome show me a special page about insecure url and i just allow it by click on **Proceed to localhost (unsafe)**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Learn about CORS, try `crossorigin.me` is work fine

Example:
https://crossorigin.me/https://fr.s.us/js/jquery-ui.css

Not show a message error and continue page white, u need see error is try

http://cors.io/?u=https://fr.s.us/js/jquery-ui.css

enjoin us ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was the `<base href="https://domain.ext/">` tag.

After removing, it was OK. Cannot really understand why it was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get data from an https that does not have certificate. Change "https://" to "http://". Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It was on Chrome for Android in my case. 
All the static files served from a CDN with a CNAME that's SSL encrypted were not showing up. On Chrome desktop, it all showed fine.

[Broken SSL cert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XF6Z.jpg)

When I properly added the certs in ca_bundle the files displayed correctly.

Chrome for Android takes encryption seriously unlike Desktop.
I hope this saves you time and stress

Answer (score 0):

If you use chrome, you can make a shortcut，right click and edit the shortcut's target, append this after target's string:

```
--ignore-certificate-errors
```

The complete string looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode and make it like this: `$_GET[]`.