# Can I use CORS to fix an ssl certificate error?

Tags: https, insecure-connection

I have an application running on server A (https://a.com.br) that has a html page that access a javascript file that is in B (https://b.com.br) server. In which of the servers I have to enable CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to avoid the need to install the certificate in browsers?

Comment: Certificate? What does that have to Cross-Origin-Access? What is the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: "A javascript file", as in *a script*, does not need CORS at all.

Comment: I get the message: GET https://b.com.br/js/x.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: Look that I'm running my application under SSL

Comment: In what browser? But yes, cors is the wrong tool for this problem.

Comment: Chrome. How to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Console errors. Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_INSECURE\_RESPONSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083453/console-errors-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response)