# how to get load my site from server without clean storage in browser console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angularjs web application, after hosted web application to server then not working perfectly.

whenever clear the browser console then only my site working perfectly, and following error is there in my console

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

If I login and logout from my site then hit the reload button then same problem only images are loading, So here again have to 
clear the storage in browser console then it will work fine.

why it is happening, every time irritating me any other solution is there please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Different ways to look into this issue :**

1. start Chrome in incognito mode with extensions disabled (ctrl+shift+n) and see if your page works now. Note that by default all extensions will be already disabled in incognito mode unless you've specifically set them to run (via chrome://extensions).

**Reference :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590757/4116300

2. If you are requesting the resources over SSL it is likely the certificate is invalid. Either it is self-signed and has not been added to your browser/OS exceptions or it is otherwise invalid.
   Try the URI directly in the same browser and inspect the certificate.

**Reference :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/22083823/4116300