# Chrome fails to load resource

Tags: google-chrome, logging, browser, cross-browser

I'm trying to display a picture on my webpage that I uploaded with PHP, however, when the page loads, the picture keeps pending for a while and soon I get this error: (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
I took a look at [Chrome's net-internals](http://chrome://net-internals/#events), but I can't find the relevant error message. (This Problem happens in other browsers too) Here is the log:

```
17460: URL_REQUEST
http://localhost/profile_pics/Vulturemox_pic.png
Start Time: 2017-08-14 13:24:31.954

t=287810 [st=    0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=47819]
                     --> priority = "LOWEST"
                     --> url = "http://localhost/profile_pics/Vulturemox_pic.png"
t=287810 [st=    0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=287810 [st=    0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=47818]
                       --> load_flags = 33026 (BYPASS_CACHE | MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                       --> method = "GET"
                       --> url = "http://localhost/profile_pics/Vulturemox_pic.png"
t=287810 [st=    0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=287810 [st=    0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=287810 [st=    0]      HTTP_CACHE_DOOM_ENTRY  [dt=0]
                         --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
t=287810 [st=    0]     +HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=1]
t=287811 [st=    1]        URL_REQUEST_SET_PRIORITY
                           --> priority = "MEDIUM"
t=287811 [st=    1]     -HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY
t=287811 [st=    1]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=287811 [st=    1]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=287811 [st=    1]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                           --> source_dependency = 17466 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=287811 [st=    1]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 17467 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=287811 [st=    1]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=287811 [st=    1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=287811 [st=    1]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                           --> GET /profile_pics/Vulturemox_pic.png HTTP/1.1
                               Host: localhost
                               Connection: keep-alive
                               Pragma: no-cache
                               Cache-Control: no-cache
                               User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
                               Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
                               Referer: http://localhost/index.php?login=success
                               Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                               Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
                               Cookie: [226 bytes were stripped]
t=287811 [st=    1]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=287811 [st=    1]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=23907]
t=287811 [st=    1]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=23906]
                           --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=311717 [st=23907]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_RESTART_AFTER_ERROR
                           --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=311718 [st=23908]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=311718 [st=23908]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=2]
t=311718 [st=23908]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                           --> source_dependency = 17476 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=311720 [st=23910]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 17477 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=311720 [st=23910]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=311721 [st=23911]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=311721 [st=23911]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                           --> GET /profile_pics/Vulturemox_pic.png HTTP/1.1
                               Host: localhost
                               Connection: keep-alive
                               Pragma: no-cache
                               Cache-Control: no-cache
                               User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
                               Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
                               Referer: http://localhost/index.php?login=success
                               Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                               Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
                               Cookie: [226 bytes were stripped]
t=311721 [st=23911]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=311721 [st=23911]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=23907]
t=311721 [st=23911]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=23907]
                           --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=335628 [st=47818]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
                         --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=335628 [st=47818]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                       --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
t=335629 [st=47819]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=335629 [st=47819] -REQUEST_ALIVE
                     --> net_error = -101 (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing cookies and then loading the page.
If that doesn't work, Check your certificates. 
Most probably your'e using wrong version of the certificate, or your certificate is expired. 
This question have been answered before as well. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083453/console-errors-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response).

Comment: Thanks, now I enabled the SSL-certificate and entered https at the start of the url and it works